# SDL image error while building gmapping

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While building the gmapping package in my embedded system (odroid-x), i got this error:

Building CXX object CMakeFiles/image_loader.dir/src/image_loader.o
/home/linaro/ros/navigation/map_server/src/image_loader.cpp:43:27: fatal error: SDL/SDL_image.h: No such file or directory

It seems that I do not have the SDL_image.h file. If i download the file, where go i have to place it in? However it run just fine in my laptop. Can anyone tell me whats the problem? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68896/sdl-image-error-while-building-gmapping/) by [Andrick](https://answers.ros.org/users/5397/andrick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Peter Zhao](https://answers.ros.org/users/22372/peter-zhao/) on 2015-05-07**:
Have you solved the problem?If you have ,please tell me how to solve it .Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same issue when building the navigation stack,you can use the Synaptic to install not only the package libsdl-image but also the libsdl-image-dev!

---

Originally posted by [zq7734509](https://answers.ros.org/users/22802/zq7734509/) with karma: 26 on 2015-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1